# Get array of attribute values, along with an attribute from a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've gotten close, I believe.  My current query is this

```
items = Item.select("items.icon, items.name, item_types.name AS type, items.level, items.rarity, items.vendor_value")
.joins(:item_type)
.where("item_types.name = '#{params[:item_type]}'")
```

This gets me an array of Item objects that at least respond to `:type` with the item_type.name.

What I am looking for is an array of arrays that look so:

```
[icon, name, item_type.name, level, rarity, vendor_value]
```

I've already had it working fairly easily, but it is important to me that this be done in one fell swoop via sql, instead of creating a map afterwards, because there are times where I need to respond with 40k+ items and need this to be as fast as possible.

Not sure how to go from the above to an array of attributes, without performing a map.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pluck` method does precisely what you want. In your case, it would look like this:

```
items = Item.joins(:item_type)
            .where("item_types.name = ?", params[:item_type])
            .pluck("items.icon", "items.name", "item_types.name AS type",
                   "items.level", "items.rarity", "items.vendor_value")
```

I also changed the `where` call to use parameterization instead of string interpolation—interpolation isn't recommended, especially when you're getting a value from the user.

Further reading:

[Official documentation for pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck)

[An in-depth explanation of how to use pluck](http://viget.com/extend/pluck-subset-rails-activerecord-model-attributes)

Comment: Thanks!  I've used pluck, but not with multiple values before.  I didn't know it could do that.  Very useful.